# How to get logger level as string value

Tags: python, logging

Using `getEffectiveLevel` I can query what the logger current level is:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('top')
level_number = logger.getEffectiveLevel()
```

The returned by `getEffectiveLevel` method value is the integer. I wonder if there is a way of querying a corresponding the string value such as "DEBUG" or "INFO" instead of an integer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you place the result of a call to the object's `getEffectiveLevel()` method into the `logging` module's `getLevelName()` class method, you get returned to you the string representation of the level:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('blah')
str_level = logging.getLevelName(log.getEffectiveLevel())

print(str_level)
```

Output:

```
WARNING
```